# how to draw path on the google maps using the current lat,log position

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I am using the google maps in my application, hence I am getting the current location using latitude and longitude, hence I am getting this location where I am going or driving. Hence, I am able to plot the current location on the map, but I don't how to draw the path using this latitude and longitude position. Hence, I am getting the current location every 5min hence I have to draw the path from where the location started to still in the current location.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to this link [link]http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/07/draw-polyline-in-google-map-version-2.html

Answer (score 0):

First you have to store all position which you are getting in every 5 minutes then you can use following code to draw line on map:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

LatLng position1 = new LatLng(lat,long);
points.add(position1);

LatLng position2 = new LatLng(lat,long);
points.add(position2);

lineOptions.addAll(points);
lineOptions.width(5);

    gMap.addPolyline(lineOptions); // gMap is object of GoogleMap
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply I don't want to use the PolylineOptions i need use some other because it display the path in the straight line i need to show in the ways of map